# JSON/XML-RPC over TCP and Message Framing

Tags: tcp, json-rpc

I was thinking about JSON/XML-RPC over HTTP vs TCP. In case of HTTP, the HTTP request and response provide a message framing mechanism. However, since TCP is a stream,

1. How are RPC messages framed?
2. Does the RPC spec dictate that?
3. Are there any other standards defining framing mechanisms?
4. Is there one mechanism more often used than the other?

I'm trying to guage this before inventing a framing mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many framing standards, HTTP being one of them.  Websocket being another, on top of HTTP, more suited for bidirectional streams.

JSON-RPC 2.0 does not concern itself with transport, intentionally.

(1.0 had some transport specifics, that was removed in the new version.)

Comment: That leaves an annoying unspecified gap between JSON-RPC and TCP. Is there a standard for JSON-RPC framing over plain TCP sockets?

Answer (score 0):

RFC 7484 provides a framing standard for "JSON text sequences": https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7464

Summary: Each JSON message is prefixed with a `0x1E` byte (which can't appear unescaped in a JSON message) and is suffixed with `0x0A` (linefeed).

Note, however, that this is not part of the JSON-RPC specification.  There are libraries that support it as part of their JSON-RPC implementation.